# pjax request change status to canceled as soon as it fires

Tags: javascript, pjax

here is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '#global-search-button', function() {


    $.pjax({
        url: "http://localhost/project/brows",
        container: '#pjax-container',
        timeout: 9000000 ,
    })

});
```

when i click on the button

[image]

her here is more info on request

```
Request URL: http://localhost/project/brows?_pjax=%23pjax-container
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/project/brows
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
X-PJAX: true
X-PJAX-Container: #pjax-container
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
_pjax: #pjax-container
```

i have to add some more info to be able to post the question , so here it is

Comment: A "dumb" reason I've come across way too often for immediately cancelled requests is an installed and active ad blocker.

Comment: @hretic any response text in the http call?

Comment: @Harshana no its empty

Comment: Is the localhost server running on port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason was very simple and odd , basically if the `href` of the link should be a `#` it would cancel as soon as it fires .... i changed it to `javascript:void(0)` and it worked

Comment: setting `href ="javascript:void(0)"` instead of # worked for me. Do you happen to know more details on this? The other solution I saw was putting `$.pjax.xhr = null` after `$pjax.reload`.

Comment: @JairusMartin i'm guessing # means its a internal link , basically link to an `id` inside the page .. maybe that's why

Comment: I found setting the `href = null` like so also works: `Html::a('RefreshGrid', null ,[...]);`.

Answer (score 2):

Often I had a similar problem because I included the hostname as well.

Try calling pjax without it like so

```
$.pjax({
  url: "/project/brows",
  container: '#pjax-container',
  timeout: 9000000,
})
```